# Subscripted variable expansion on NUL delimited words in zsh

Tags: zsh

I have data produced by `file`, which is identifying the mime-types of all the files in a directory (or directories). The result is a list, with commands on the left and mime-types on the right. By default, these two values (or strings?) are delimited by a colon (:). I want to instead delimit the commands from their mime-types with the NUL character. So,

`files=( ${(f)"$(file --print0 --mime-type **/*)"} )`

This seems to work.

`print -l ${files[@]}` gives:

```
cs:           text/x-shellscript
da:           text/x-shellscript
dns-test:     text/x-shellscript
```

Or, `print -l ${(V)files[@]}` gives:

```
cs^@:           text/x-shellscript
da^@:           text/x-shellscript
dns-test^@:     text/x-shellscript
```

But, when using subscripting to match the first **word**, the output is the first **character** instead. So,

```
for f in "${files[@]}"; do
  print "${f[(pws:\0:)1]}"
done
```

This only prints the first **character** of each array element (each line outputted by `file`):

```
c
d
d
```

If I instead omit the specification of `(ps:\0:)`, thus using the default of separating on white-space, then I do get the first word of each element. So,

```
for f in "${files[@]}"; do
  print "${f[(w)1]}"
done
```

This works:

```
cs
da
dns-test
```

But I don't want to rely on white-space. I want to use a safer delimiter like NUL. Note that I also tried the subscript `[(pws:\000:)1]`, but this also only produced the first **character**.

How can I identify words delimited by NUL when working with subscripts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

File paths can contain newline characters. That's why several utilities that report files or things about files offer you to delimit records with NULs instead of newline as 0 is the only  byte value that cannot occur in a file path.

If you're splitting the output on newline as you do with `${(f)"$(file...)"}`, you're defeating the purpose.

`file` is a bit of an odd one in that it doesn't use NUL as its record delimiter, but uses it to delimit the file path in its output record (which remains loosely defined).

```
$ ls
':\0:'$'\n'':\1:'  'a'$'\n''b'
$ file --print0 --mime-type -- ./* | sed -n l
./:\\0:$
:\\1:\000: application/x-xz$
./a$
b\000:       application/zip$
```

So its record is `<file-path><NUL><colon><some-spaces><mime-type><newline>` which makes it unnecessarily more difficult to parse (even impossible if the text contains newlines which in the case of `--mime-type` thankfully should not be the case).

Here, you could do:

```
typeset -A mime_type
file --print0 --mime-type --no-pad --separator '' ./**/* |
  while
    IFS= read -rd $'\0' file &&
      IFS=' ' read -r type
  do
    mime_type[$file]=$type
  done
```

Where the first `read` with NUL as `-d`elimiter reads the NUL-delimited file path and the second reads the newline-delimited mime-type (trimming the leading whitespace with IFS processing).

The `--no-pad` turns the `<some-spaces>` into a single space, `--separator ''` removes the colon, so we have `<file-path><NUL><space><mime-type><newline>`

In the loop, we fill the `$mime_type` associative array, so you can thereafter get the type of a given file with `$mime_type[./given/file]` or list the files of a given type with `print -rC1 -- ${(k)mime_type[(R)text/plain]}`.

---

As to why `$scalar[(pws[\0])1]` doesn't split on NULs, that's [a bug in current versions of zsh](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2022/msg01280.html). The behaviour is the same as in `$array[(pws[])1]` suggesting zsh fails to escape the NUL as it otherwise usually does so you end up splitting on the empty string. That missing escaping affects other separators like all those containing byte values 0x83 to 0xa2 (such as `á` which in UTF-8 is encoded as 0xc3 0xa1).

Without `s[separator]`, I find it splits on `$IFS` characters (not whitespace, another bug, a documentation one this time), NUL being in the default value of `$IFS`, so you could do: `IFS=$'\0'; first_non_empty_NUL_separated_field=$scalar[(w)1]`, but you could also use the `0` (short for `ps[\0]`) *parameter expansion flag*:

```
non_empty_NUL_separated_fields=( ${(0)scalar} )
```

```
NUL_separated_fields=( "${(0@)scalar}" )
```

(and then `first=$NUL_separated_fields[1]`).

Or in one go `first=${${(0)scalar}[1]}`.

Or you can use the `${scalar%%pattern}` Korn shell operator:

```
before_first_NUL=${scalar%%$'\0'*}
```

Or IFS-splitting:

```
IFS=$'\0'
NUL_separated_fields=( $=scalar )
```

Or ksh93-style `${param/pattern[/replacement]}`:

```
first=${scalar/$'\0'*}
```

---

Some comments on your code:

- in `file --print0 --mime-type **/*`, if any of the file paths starts with `-`, that would be taken as an option to `file`. You could change it to `file --print0 --mime-type -- **/*` to avoid that but that still doesn't work properly if there's a file called `-` in the current working directory. Using `./**/*` avoids both problems (and further problems down the line).
- `@`, whether as a parameter expansion flag or as `[@]` or `$@` only really makes sense when quoted, to prevent removal of empty elements. `${files[@]}` in list context is the same as `$files` or `$files[@]` or `$files[*]` and expands to the non-empty elements in the array. Note that in Korn-like shells, you do also need the quotes, to prevent empty-removal but also to prevent split+glob there. Korn-like shells (contrary to most other shells or languages) also require the braces, and `$files` alone expand to the element of indice 0, not all the elements.
- With `print`, you generally want to use the `-r` option without which `print` does some backslash processing, and you almost always want to use the `--` or `-` option delimiter without which you introduce command injection vulnerabilities. `print $var` is an ACE vulnerability. Like in the Korn shell where that builtin comes from, you want `print -r - $var` or `print -r -- $var` (though in ksh, you'd need `print -r - "$var"`).
- `print -rC1 -- $list` is generally better than `print -rl -- $list` to print a list `r`aw on `1` `C`olumn as the latter prints an empty line if passed no argument.

Comment: This is a great workaround, but is it possible to use `\0` as the delimiter in `"${f[(pws:\0:)1]}"` as the OP wanted? I had assumed that it isn't, since bash at least can't deal with NUL in variables as far as I know, but you said zsh has no issue with NUL. Does that mean it could do something like this, somehow?

Comment: @terdon, it's not a work around. The OP's approach of splitting on newline and then split each resulting line on NULs is wrong. Now, why `$scalar[(pws:\0:)1]` doesn't split on NULs looks like a bug. You could always use `IFS=$'\0'` and `$scalar[(w)1]` or `${${(0)scalar}[1]}` as a work around.

Comment: I don't think this works for me. In my program, I want both the filename (on the left) and its type. This way I can run a loop, checking if the right side contains a specific string (text, audio, image...), and if so, then storing/printing the filename on the left. From there, I can rm/trash all the files of a specific mime type in the directory.

Comment: Also, thanks for the suggestion with `read`. That's good to know!

Comment: @PoundHash, that's exactly what it does: loop over `file`'s output with the file in `$file` and the type in `$type`. In the body of the loop here we set the `$mime_type` associative array, but you can do anything else you want. With the types in an associative array, you can do things like `rm -f ${(k)mime_type[(R)application/x-pie-executable]}` to delete files of a given type.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you sir. I'll have to study this for a bit.

Comment: Why is it defeating the purpose of using NUL by splitting on newline with `${(f)"$(file...)"}`? Why not have two delimiters in one line (or *record*, I guess I should say)? I'm familiar with the term *record* from AWK, but I don't think I've come across it in the zsh/GNU docs.

Comment: @PoundHash, you use NUL instead of NL as delimiters for file paths because NL is valid in a file path but NUL is not. That's why you have `find -print0`, `du --files0-from` and why `file --files-from` is broken by design. If you split the output of `file` on NLs, you're breaking appart multi-line file paths. "record" here is the unit of information returned by `file`. That can't be a "line" because a file path can be made of several line, hence the NUL's. `file`'s record however is the contenation of a NUL delimited record and a line ( a newline delimited record) which makes it a bit awkward.